# Awk reading fields in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm trying to read two text files so I can check if some fields are the same in both files. I can easily extract the fields in command line but something goes wrong when doing from a bash script.

I generate the file (list of files) in a for loop (tried echo and printf commands)

```
printf "$servidor1$gfs1_dir$gfs1_file\n" >> server1
```

You can see the output of cat command

```
cat server1

ftp://server/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.2014011400/gfs.t00z.pgrbf00.grib2
ftp://server/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.2014011400/gfs.t00z.pgrbf06.grib2
```

If I try from the command line it runs fine. Two lines/records in the file are shown:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="/"} {print $11}' server1

gfs.t00z.pgrbf00.grib2
gfs.t00z.pgrbf06.grib2
```

But if I want to set FNR there comes the error (in the script awk it is used to build a variable named *fremote*)

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="/"} { RS="\n"} {FNR == 1} {print $11}' server1

gfs.t00z.pgrbf00.grib2
gfs.t00z.pgrbf06.grib2
```

The same occurs when I create the fremote var in the bash script (i stands for the loop variable in the script)

```
i=1
fremote=`awk -v i=$i 'BEGIN { FS="/"} { RS="\n"} {FNR == i} {print $11}' servidor1-file.list`

echo $fremote

gfs.t00z.pgrbf00.grib2 gfs.t00z.pgrbf06.grib2
```

Maybe it is related with the way server1 file is created, maybe how it is accessed by awk. I can't find the right point.

Thanks in advance for your help. I'll go on working o this issue and post the answer if found.

**EDIT**

From the comments I add the code in the bash script where awk is invoked (hope it helps to understand what I'm trying). I have two files, list of local files and list of remote files in the server. I try to build two vars flocal and fremote to check if they are the same. Maybe there are easier and smarter ways to check.

```
while [ $i -le $nlocal ]  
   do
   flocal=`awk -v i=$i 'FNR == i {print $1}' lista.local`
   fremote=`awk -v i=$i 'BEGIN { FS="/"} {FNR == $i} {print $11}' $2`

   if [ "$flocal" != "$fremote" ]; then 
      echo "Some file missing"  >> $log
      flag_check_descarga=0
   else
      contador=$(($contador + 1))
      echo $contador "Download OK" $flocal  >> $log
   fi
   i=$(( $i + 1 ))
done
```

Comment: usually `FS,OFS,RS,ORS...` should be set in `BEGIN` block. btw, why you want to set `FNR`? and what do you want to get?

Comment: What are you doing with `RS` there? Why are you setting it for each line? `==` is equality not assignment. If you get an error you should show us the error text. I don't know that setting FNR is going to do what you expect (I don't know what awk is going to do when you change that, possibly nothing).

Comment: @Kent In the script I use `FNR == i` where i is the loop variable as I want to check every single line.

Comment: @EtanReisner There's no error message. It just does not show the expected results, my fault.

Comment: Your goal here, ultimately, is to find out whether, for each file on the local disk, there is a similar file (by name) on the remote server? If so then you want something more like `awk -F/'NR==FNR{files[$1]=1} ($11 not in files) {printf "File missing: %s", $11}' lista.local server1` or something like that.

Comment: @EtanReisnerThis is the goal, check by name (and size) I'll try your suggestion and see but I'm leaving now. It will be tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have size in that script/data anywhere that I can see.

Comment: Actually, there is no size in this piece of script. It comes later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.

```
awk -v i="$i" 'BEGIN { FS="/"; RS="\n"}
    FNR == i {print $11}' server1
```

The `BEGIN { ... }` block contains actions to perform when the script is starting. The `FNR==i { ... }` block contains actions to perform when reading the *i*th line of a file.

An unconditional block `{ ... }` contains actions to perform unconditionally, i.e. for every input line. But `FNR==i` is not a meaningful action; it is just a boolean which is true when the line number of the file is equal to *i*. It is an excellent *condition* but as an *action* it doesn't do anything (that you can detect from the outside).

However, the task you appear to be trying to solve would be easier to solve with a single Awk script -- the one posted by @EtanReisner in a comment looks good to me -- or just

```
comm -23 <(sort lista.remote) <(sort lista.local)
```

or even, if the files are already sorted,

```
comm -23 lista.local lista.remote
```

Wrapping up, you could end up with something like

```
sort -o lista.local lista.local  # make sure lista.local is sorted
awk -F/ '{ print $11 }' server1 |
sort |
comm -23 - lista.local
```

In keeping with the Unix spirit, this will quietly succeed if there are no differences, and fail (exit with a non-zero exit code) and print the missing entries if something is missing.

If you want to print the successfully downloaded files as well, just `cat lista.local`, or maybe something like `sed 's/^/Successfully downloaded /' lista.local`

Comment: In the script I use `FNR == i` where i is the loop variable as I want to check every single line. Thanks @tripleee

Comment: I don't understand that `FNR` comment. awk looks at every line unless you do something to make it skip lines.

Comment: Didn't know about comm, will try. Thanks

Comment: I added a snippet and refactored some of the answer, and so deleted some comments of mine which were now obsolete.  In particular, the logic is now correct for checking a download (remote has all the files, local may be missing some).

Comment: Hi @triplee You were right and the syntax was wrong. Now it works in my example files, will translate into the global script. Thanks